# Using rm in a makefile on Windows with MSYS

Tags: windows, permissions, makefile, latex, pdflatex

I have the following code in my makefile to remove files I don't want to persist after the tex file has been compiled succesfully.

```
grep '^OUTPUT ' $*.fls \
    | sed -e 's/^OUTPUT //' \
    | grep -vx $@ \
    | xargs rm
rm $*.fls
rm -f $*.bbl $*.blg
```

I get the following error after the pdf has been produced succesfully.

```
rm: cannot remove `00_Master_Thesis.log': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `00_Master_Thesis.nlo': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `00_Master_Thesis.aux': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `00_Master_Thesis.out': Permission denied
make.exe": *** [00_Master_Thesis.pdf] Error 123
```

I tried to add several commands to get the right to delete those files and checked the rights on the folder containing these files. I also tried to start cmd as admin but nothing seems to help.

The same makefile is working fine on my Ubuntu system.
How can I let make delete those files on Windows, too?

## EDIT:

The problem seems to be, that pdflatex.exe does not quit after the pdf has been written. I even can't delete those files manually because according to the windows explorer they are still opened in pdflatex.exe.

After I killed pdflatex.exe the error message changed now only showing:

```
rm: cannot remove `00_Master_Thesis.log': Permission denied
make.exe": *** [00_Master_Thesis.pdf] Error 123
```

Now in addition to the log file only the *.log, *.bbl, *.blg, *.fls, *.ilg and *.nls files aren't removed. The *.aux, *.out and *.nlo files are gone for good after make finishes, which is at least a step in the right direction. ^^

How can I get pdflatex.exe get to quit or release the files so rm can remove them?

Comment: But is `pdflatex` actually running? Since ms-windows uses file locking, it could be that this is a case of locks not being removed when `pdflatex` exits.

Comment: According to the task manager, yes, pdflatex.exe is still running after make finishes.

Comment: If you run `pdflatex` manually does it exit when it is finished or does it also stay running? Does redirecting standard input/output/error from/to `/dev/null` help here?

Comment: What options do you give `pdflatex`? I'd suggest `-interaction batchmode` and `-halt-on-error`.

Comment: @RolandSmith Awesome. I had the `-halt-on-error` option but not `-interaction batchmode`. Adding this option did the trick! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [@RonaldSmith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888978/using-rm-in-a-makefile-on-windows-with-msys#comment61346771_36888978), try adding both options:

`-halt-on-error` and `-interaction batchmode`,

then it should work.